# bash script to close a port

Tags: command-line, networking, bash

Can someone check what I am doing wrong here:

```
killp() {sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:"$@"); l; }
```

I want to generalize this case to any port.

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
killp () {
  sudo kill `lsof -t -i:$*`
}
```

Comment: thank you. I liked you post but i don`t have enough of points for my vote to be visible yet.

Comment: I don't think you can `sudo` a shell function, and as long as sudo clears the environment, even `export -f killp` doesn't help. You'd need to put it in a script instead.

Comment: Oh you're right, sudo will not work unless the root user has this bash function setup, so it's probably better to use a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I also just figured it out. kinda. Works.

```
killp() {sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:"$@")}
```

I had a custom alias for `l` (`alias l="LC_COLLATE=C ls -gAG -x -1 --group-directories-first --sort=extension"`) which is unnecessary here.

Comment: Nick's answer is better. Simple. Sudo is also unnecessary in my function

Answer (score 0):

`"$@"` expands to all parameters of the function, as separate words. `killp 22 33` would then expand to `...lsof -t -i:22 33`, which may or may not be what you want. If it isn't, just use `"$1"` instead to only take the first argument.

Something like `-sTCP:LISTEN` might be useful here too, if you only want to close a listening (server) port and not outgoing connections.

Comment: oh nice! now I know what "$@" and "$1" mean. Thanks so much for explaining notation.